# How to translate model name and properties with Reform + dry-validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, reform

I'm in a project where I'm using the gem trailblazer(and by that, I'm using reform too) with dry-validations.
And kind of found how to translate error messages - I'm putting `config.messages = :i18n` inside each contract/reform class, since I didn't find how to configure it glogablly to every reform class I have.

BUT, at least, I did reached it.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to translate my reform class's properties and "model_name". The great would be to just configure it to use the model's translations(e.g.: UserForm being translated just as User model), but I didn't even find the format to write the locales for my reform classes.

So, what I want to do is:
- Make reform classes give the same translations as it's respective models
- OR know the structure of reform's locales ymls

Comment: Did you figure out this one?

Comment: No, I couldn't firegure out how to do it, so I continued with a manual translation while in the project, and now I'm not working on it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For a global configuration on Rails 7 with the Reform gem. I do the next in
config/initializers/reform.rb

```
Dry::Validation::Contract.config.messages.load_paths << 'config/locales/es.yml'
Dry::Validation::Contract.config.messages.load_paths << 'config/locales/en.yml'
Dry::Validation::Contract.config.messages.default_locale = I18n.locale
```